# Algorithm not showing in multicol

Tags: multicol, algorithm2e, algorithmic

When I am in the multicol environment, my algorithms are not showing. The page is simply blank. Full TeX code available here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym, marvosym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,dirtytalk}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{mathptm}
\usepackage[boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{epsf}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\scriptsize


\section{Sorting}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{InsertionSort}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Input: A
\FOR{$i = 0$ to $n - 2$}
        \STATE{$j = i$}
        \WHILE{$j \ge 0$ and $A[j + 1] < A[j]$}
                \STATE{swap $A[j]$ and $A[j + 1]$}
                \STATE{j = j - 1}
        \ENDWHILE
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}



\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Would like some help on making my algorithm show, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider reviewing the `.log` when odd things happen. In this case you would have seen the following reported by (La)TeX:

> Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols'
> environment!.

To avoid this, floats should not float within `multicols`, which is available through the `[H]`ERE option (provided by [`floats`](//ctan.org/pkg/floats) or the `algorithm` environment from [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \section{Sorting}

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{InsertionSort}
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \STATE Input: A
      \FOR{$i = 0$ to $n - 2$}
        \STATE{$j = i$}
        \WHILE{$j \ge 0$ and $A[j + 1] < A[j]$}
          \STATE{swap $A[j]$ and $A[j + 1]$}
          \STATE{j = j - 1}
        \ENDWHILE
      \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```